# How to install kubectl with ansible?

Tags: ansible

I would like to install https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/. 
The installation instructions are described as follows:

```
  ....
  curl -s https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
  echo "deb https://apt.kubernetes.io/ kubernetes-xenial main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/kubernetes.list
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install -y kubectl
```

How to translate the instructions above into Ansible tasks?

What I have tried is:

```
  - name: Add kubectl GPG apt Key
    apt_key:
      url: https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg
      state: present
```

Here I even do not know, if I have to first add `get_url` task or add it directly like above.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. We install Rundeck, which follows similar steps, using the following Ansible code:

```
- name: add rundeck apt repository key
  become: true
  apt_key:
    url: https://bintray.com/user/downloadSubjectPublicKey?username=bintray

- name: add rundeck apt repository
  become: true
  apt_repository:
    repo: 'deb https://rundeck.bintray.com/rundeck-deb /'
    filename: rundeck

- name: install rundeck dependencies
  become: true
  apt:
    name: openjdk-8-jdk

- name: install rundeck and rundeck-cli
  become: true
  apt:
    name: "{{ item }}"
  loop:
    - rundeck
    - rundeck-cli
```

Use that as an example and you should be good to go. The [`apt_repository`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/apt_repository_module.html) module runs `apt-get update` automatically when new repositories are added.

Answer (score 1):

I created the following ansible tasks that download and install the latest kubectl release on my raspberry pi. Furthermore, it also performs a checksum test, to check the validity of the downloaded binary. The tasks are based on the [installation manual](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-macos/) of kubectl.

```
- name: Get latest kubectl version
  uri:
    url: https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt
    return_content: yes
  register: version

- name: Download the latest kubectl release
  uri:
    url: https://dl.k8s.io/release/{{ version.content }}/bin/linux/arm/kubectl
    dest: /home/{{ ansible_user }}
  register: kubectl

- name: Download the kubectl checksum file
  uri:
    url: https://dl.k8s.io/{{ version.content }}/bin/linux/arm/kubectl.sha256
    dest: /home/{{ ansible_user }}

- name: Download the kubectl checksum file
  uri:
    url: https://dl.k8s.io/{{ version.content }}/bin/linux/arm/kubectl.sha256
    dest: /home/{{ ansible_user }}

- name: Validate the kubectl binary against the checksum file
  shell: echo "$(cat kubectl.sha256)  kubectl" | sha256sum --check
  register: result

- name: Assert that the kubectl binary is OK
  vars:
    expected: "kubectl: OK"
  assert:
    that:
      - result.stdout == expected
    fail_msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"
    success_msg: "{{ result.stdout }}"

- name: Move kubectl and change permissions
  file:
    src: "{{ kubectl.path }}"
    dest: /usr/local/bin/kubectl
    state: hard
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: "+x"

- name: Check if kubectl is installed
  shell: kubectl version --client
  register: client
  failed_when: client.rc > 1
```

Comment: This script simply just doesn't work.

Comment: Please see my script below. There were several things wrong. It didn't work for cases where:

1). The home directory doesn't exist
2). The kubectl binary is already in the home dir
3). The checksum in the home dir
4). The kubectl binary in /usr/local
5). The website dl.k8s.io can return both a 304 as well as a 200. 
6). The checksum comparison did not work properly. 
7). The copying of the file did not work properly
8). The script doesn't clean up after itself.

Answer (score 1):

I had to install kubectl via ansible and I spent some time to create an Ansible script following the official [Kubectl linux installation instruction](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl-linux/)

This is working for me both using Ansible via command line and using Packer tool to create AWS AMIs:

```
---

- name: Get latest kubectl version
  uri:
    url: https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt
    return_content: yes
  register: version

- name: create kubectl versioned directory
  file:
    path: /opt/kubectl-{{ version.content }}
    state: directory
  become: true

- name: Download the latest kubectl release
  uri:
    url: https://dl.k8s.io/release/{{ version.content }}/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
    dest: /opt/kubectl-{{ version.content }}
  register: kubectl
  become: true

- name: Download the kubectl checksum
  uri:
    url: https://dl.k8s.io/release/{{ version.content }}/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl.sha256
    dest: /opt/kubectl-{{ version.content }}
  register: kubectl
  become: true

- name: Get kubectl sha256sum
  shell: sha256sum /opt/kubectl-{{ version.content }}/kubectl | cut -d " " -f1
  register: file_shasum

- set_fact:
    shasum1={{ file_shasum.stdout }}

- debug: var=shasum1
  run_once: true

- name: get sha256sum value from file
  command: cat /opt/kubectl-{{ version.content }}/kubectl.sha256
  register: downloaded_shasum

- set_fact:
    shasum2={{ downloaded_shasum.stdout }}

- debug: var=shasum2
  run_once: true

- name: Assert that the kubectl binary is OK
  assert:
    that:
      - file_shasum.stdout == downloaded_shasum.stdout
    fail_msg: "Shasum does not correspond"
    success_msg: "kubectl shasum verified: ok"

- name: Change kubectl file permission
  file:
    path: "/opt/kubectl-{{ version.content }}/kubectl"
    mode: '0755'
  become: true

- name: create a symlink to kubectl
  file:
    src: "/opt/kubectl-{{ version.content }}/kubectl"
    dest: "/usr/bin/kubectl"
    state: link
  become: true
```

Any comment appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use URI module in order in place of curl command. For more info https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/uri_module.html

   ```
   tasks:
       - name: post to consul
       uri:
          url: http://marathon.service.consul:8080/v2/apps/
          method: POST
          body: "{{ lookup('file','mesos-consul.json') }}"
          body_format: json
          headers:
             Content-Type: "application/json"
   ```
2. You can register the result of this call into a variable. i.e. storing the result into ansible variable to be used in next step like apt-key add- in your case. How to save results in a variable here -https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables
3. Executing shell commands and switching to sudo user, you can find it here: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html and https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/become.html
4. Once you have understood the above, finally you have to just write a yaml file with the tasks you want and in order you want.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem myself and none of the solutions on this page really gave me the script that I needed, so I -- based off of Cloudkollectiv's script -- built a new one. This is what works on amd64.

```
---
- name: Install KubeCtl
  hosts: all
  become: yes


  tasks:
  - name: Check if home directory exists
    stat:
      path: /home/{{ ansible_user }}
    register: home_dir

  - name: Create home directory if it doesn't exist
    file:
      path: /home/{{ ansible_user }}
      state: directory
    when: not home_dir.stat.exists

  - name: Check for kubectl binary in home directory
    stat:
      path: /home/{{ ansible_user }}/kubectl
    register:
      kubectl_binary_home

  - name: Check for kubectl checksum in home directory
    stat:
      path: /home/{{ ansible_user }}/kubectl
    register:
      kubectl_chksum_home

  - name: Delete kubectl binary from home directory
    file:
      path: /home/{{ ansible_user }}/kubectl
      state: absent
    when: kubectl_binary_home.stat.exists

  - name: Delete checksum file from home directory
    file:
      path: /home/{{ ansible_user }}/kubectl.sha256
      state: absent
    when: kubectl_chksum_home.stat.exists

  - name: Get latest kubectl version
    uri:
      url: https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt
      return_content: yes
      status_code: 200, 304
    register: version

  - name: Download the latest kubectl release
    uri:
      url: https://dl.k8s.io/release/{{ version.content }}/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
      dest: /home/{{ ansible_user }}
      status_code: 200, 304
    register: kubectl

  - name: Download the kubectl checksum file
    uri:
      url: https://dl.k8s.io/{{ version.content }}/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl.sha256
      dest: /home/{{ ansible_user }}
      status_code: 200, 304

  - name: Validate the kubectl binary against the checksum file
    shell: echo "$(cat /home/{{ ansible_user }}/kubectl.sha256)"
    register: source_chksum

  - name: Compute new checksum of kubectl binary
    shell: sha256sum /home/{{ ansible_user }}/kubectl | awk '{print $1}'
    register: new_chksum

  - name: Assert that the kubectl binary is OK
    vars:
      expected: "kubectl: OK"
    assert:
      that:
        - source_chksum.stdout == new_chksum.stdout
      fail_msg: "Checksum does not match {{ source_chksum.stdout }} != {{ new_chksum.stdout }}"
      success_msg: "Successfully validated"

  - name: Check if kubectl installed in /usr/local/bin
    stat:
      path: /usr/local/bin/kubectl
    register: kubectl_binary_usr_local_bin

  - name: Delete kubectl binary from /usr/local/bin if it exists
    file:
      path: /usr/local/bin/kubectl
      state: absent
    when: kubectl_binary_home.stat.exists

  - name: Copy kubectl and change permissions
    copy:
      src: "{{ kubectl.path }}"
      remote_src: yes
      dest: /usr/local/bin/kubectl
      owner: root
      group: root
      mode: "+x"

  - name: Check if kubectl is installed
    shell: kubectl version --client
    register: client
    failed_when: client.rc > 1

  - name: remove downloaded binaries from home
    file:
      path: /home/{{ ansible_user }}/kubectl
      state: absent

  - name: remove downloaded checksums from home
    file:
      path: /home/{{ ansible_user }}/kubectl.sha256
      state: absent
```